# jQuery find dinamically added elements in the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

After hours of brain crack, I landed here.

I have a form that is saved in database and populated on select change like so.

```
$(document).on('change', '#site-number', function() {
 // some code

 // this function is adding a div with ID#image
 setupImageField();

 // NOT FINDING
 var imageField = $(document).find("#image");
});
```

Image field funtion

```
setupImageField() {
 $("#photos-container").append('<div id="image"></div>');
}
```

The element #image it's not find. Looking for a fix for this but I can`t figure out how because the element it's added within the save function that is already running.

Comment: Just use `$("#image");`, Note __identifiers__ in HTML must be __unique__

Comment: Also, if the content of the `setupImageField()` is added in an async function you'll need to use the callback

Comment: I have a feeling the actual issue is with code that is not shown here. But adding an element on change seems like that is going to result in multiple elements on the page with the same id.

Comment: Thank you for comments. The code is't adding ID's, I put it like this for better understanding. Actually it's adding some textareas with name like this: name="photo1-caption", name="photo2-caption" and so on, and the select looks like this: $(document).find('name="photo1-caption"')

Comment: Regardless of example, there's no need for `$(document).find()`, just use your name as the selector: `var $imageField = $("[name=photo1-caption]");`